# cryptoJS.MD5 on a file using JS

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, md5

I want to calculate MD5 of a file at clients end. I have done it using cryptoJS.MD5. It is wirking properly on any string input but not for the file. Can you please help me in knowing what am i missing. Thanks in advance!!

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
    <script>
    function fn()
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend=function(){
         text = (reader.result);
         reader.readAsBinaryString(document.getElementById("files").files[0]);
           var hash1 = CryptoJS.MD5(text);
            console.log("hash1="+hash1.toString());

        }
        var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message");
        console.log("hash=" + hash.toString()); 
        alert("hi");

    }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="files" id="files">
         <input type="submit" onclick="fn()">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes. Several problems here.

First, your form submits, so whatever you log to the console is gone once the page refreshes. Get rid of the form tags; after all, you're not actually submitting anything to a server.

Second, your line that starts reading the file (`readAsBinaryString`) is *inside* the callback that gets invoked when reading is completed... so reading of the file never actually starts. Move that line outside the callback.

And finally, JavaScript doesn't really have a binary string type. What we *treat* as a binary string is nonetheless still UTF-16 characters. But CryptoJS can't divine that your UTF-16 string is meant to represent binary data. So instead you'll have to explicitly say what characters-to-bytes encoding you want to use:

```
CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(text)
```